# How to add a web part zone in SharePoint using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-designer

I need to add a web part zone to a wiki page. I'm opening the page using SharePoint Designer, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way (such as a menu) to add a Web Part Zone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101513941033.aspx

> Insert a Web Part zone
>
> 1. In Office SharePoint Designer 2007, open the page where you want to
>      insert the Web Part zone.
> 2. If the Web Parts task pane is not already open, open it by clicking
>      Web Parts on the Task Panes menu.
> 3. In Design view, click the location on the page where you want to
>      insert the Web Part zone.
> 4. At the bottom of the Web Parts task pane, click New Web Part Zone.
>
>    The new Web Part zone is inserted on the page.
>      ...

Answer (score 2):

If this a page that you will be using over again in different places, consider creating a site def instead.  By editing a page in sharepoint designer, you create a "customized" version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

open your site in SPD -->insert-->sharepoint controls--> web part zone.
Note that you are unable to add a web part zone in master pages